# which mode is 555 timer in this case

Tags: timer, 555

This particular timer is made to turn off the load, after KEY1 is pressed long enough. I am not sure if it is in astable or monostable mode.

[image]

Comment: honest question: does the *name* of the mode matter to you? If it matters to you: do you know what "astable" or "monostable" *means*? (because that answers your question.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller If it is only the name that matters, I would know the answer. But isn't it that the circuit defines it?

So I have to manually re-press the momentary switch in order to repeat the cycle, this means it's monostable, right?

Comment: So, let's do this from the term out: what does "monostable" **mean**?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Mono means one. So one or isolated stable operation?

Comment: @Domenico Monostable means it's stable in one output state; i.e. if it's forced into the other state, it will eventually return to the stable one. Astable means it's stable in neither, and keeps switching. Bistable means it's stable in both, and will stay in either state indefinitely until forced to the other.

Comment: @Domenico so, in how many states is your circuit "stable", i.e., doesn't switch to the other without trigger?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I get you. Is monostable.

Comment: @Domenico not what I suggested. Where are you taking this from? Which state is the stable one, which is the unstable one, if it's monostable?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see you want me to learn something here, but I don't get what you mean - and I didn't mention "unstable". I just know what this circuit does, and it won't make sense to me to describe it as a astable/bistable.

And it makes sense to me what Heart said: "Monostable means it's stable in one output state; i.e. if it's forced into the other state, it will eventually return to the stable one."

So if this isn't the case, please just let me know where EXACTLY to look into.

Comment: "so, in how many states is your circuit "stable", i.e., doesn't switch to the other without trigger?" - It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

"Monostable"

A.k.a.: "One shot.

- Astable: keeps on switching back and forth forever; no trigger
- Monostable: switches back and forth only once per trigger

Comment: except here one trigger won't do anything. The current has to be long enough that it will fill a 1uF capacitor in order that cut off will happen.

Comment: @Domenico don't think I follow you there – something having states between it can transition with or without trigger is what defines mono/bi/astability; nothing is said about the kind of trigger.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see. I'm just struggling to combine monostable "one shot" with this particular one, because one shot has a trigger on the low tide. But that is another story. I might post a question later. Thank you for your time.